# How to pass the ArrayList between methods and classes?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, opennlp

I have this method which returns an arrayList tokens :

```
public static String[] Tokenize(String input) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-token.bin");    
    TokenizerModel model = new TokenizerModel(is);   
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new TokenizerME(model);    
    String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize(input);     
    for (String a : tokens)
        System.out.println(a);   
    is.close();
    return tokens;
}
```

I want these tokens to be used in another method:

```
public static void findName(String[] input) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-ner-person.bin");   
    TokenNameFinderModel model = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
    is.close();  
    NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME(model);   
    Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find(input);   
    for(Span s: nameSpans)
        System.out.println(s.toString());           
}
```

Also, how can I use this tokens arrayList in another class something like,

```
public class Main{
    public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Anotherclass.Tokenize(input);
        Anotherclass.findName(tokens);

    }
}
```

I'm unable to figure this out! Please help me.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: call that Tokenize () and use it

Comment: where did you declare ArrayList?

Comment: Your method does not return an `ArrayList` object but an array of Strings; they are different. Just declare a new input parameter to your method `String[] tokens` and use it to your code.

Comment: ^^ here :  String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize(input);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
Anotherclass.findName(Anotherclass.Tokenize(input));
```

Comment: But it is not giving any output of the findName method. why is that?

Comment: Is there a way I can use tokens[] in the findName method itself?

Comment: You can change the return type of findName from void to Span Array i.e Span[] and then you can use that array and make a for loop in main method do whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-use your 1st method result into the 2nd one.

```
public class Main{
     public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception
     {
         String[] tokens = Anotherclass.Tokenize(input);
         Anotherclass.findName(tokens);

     }
}
```

You still have to figure out where does your `input` variable comes from.

Comment: It is not giving any output of findName method. why is that?

Comment: Is there a way I can use tokens[] in the findName method itself?

Answer (score 0):

you created static method so you can call those method by Class name like

```
String[] SAMPLEARRAY = YOURCLASSNAME.Tokenize(String_ARRAY);
```